# Javascript issues & IE (style.display property)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

My code below is used to trigger an alternative product code. It hides the original SKU code and shows the alternative. It works perfectly on all devices except the dreaded browser IE.

```
 var togglename = function() {
  var mydiv = document.getElementById('nappi');
  if (mydiv.style.display = "initial" || mydiv.style.display = "")
    mydiv.style.display = 'none';
  else
    mydiv.style.display = 'initial'
  }

    var togglecode = function() {
  var mydiv = document.getElementsByClassName('nappi2');
 if($(mydiv).hasClass('visNappi'))
   $('.nappi2').removeClass('visNappi');
  else
$('.nappi2').addClass('visNappi');
  }
  function toggle(){
    togglename();
    togglecode();
}
```

The code is triggered by a button

```
<button id="switch1" name="switch1" onclick="toggle();" >Show / Hide</button>
```

This button basically hides and adds a separate key to a tables field.

Comment: Don't mix plain js method with jQuery, use one or the other for code consistency. Now how do you debug it? You shouldn't rely for checking purpose on value returned by computed style, this can be easily unconsistent across browser. And basically, you just want to use `toggle()/toggleClass()` jQuery methods, so use it instead

Comment: would you recommend I alter the code to use a true and false value instead? Would it be best if i done this using a checkbox instead?

Comment: I'd recommend to use relevant jQuery methods, handling all the cross browser thing for you. And i would recommend btw to use unobstrusive javascript, binding event using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code just should be:

```
function toggle(){
   $('#nappi').toggle();
   $('.nappi2').toggleClass('visNappi');
}
```

And you should bind click event using relevant jQuery method:

```
$(function(){
    $('#switch1').on('click', toggle); // do you really need referenced method here?!
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I took your advice and made the change, works perfectly.